# Launch my iPhone app on device through instruments

Tags: iphone, terminal, instruments, ui-automation, frank

An app I've created is already installed on my device that I simply want to launch using instruments.  It is already installed on my device.  I simply want to launch the app.  I am using this

`instruments -w <device_id> -t "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Resources/templates/Activity Monitor.tracetemplate" -D /tmp/ignoredtracedata.trace <app_name>`

This is what I get

`Instruments Trace Error : (null)`

I had this working at one point.  Then without making any changes the next day I came to work on it and it wasn't working `:(`.  I've tried things for a couple of hours and heven't made much progress.

I am using the Ruby gem Frank to run tests.  I'd like to launch the app in different languages which is why I want to use instruments instead of simply adding the `-d` debug flag to launch the app on the device.

Does anyone have anything that will help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly why this fixed my problem.  But I checked which processes were running with `$ ps` and instruments was running.  I just killed instruments `sudo killall instruments` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and assume that the app you're trying to run instruments on is an app you've developed? You can't use Instruments on someone else's app, or you'd have access to their written code.

If it's you're own code, why do it through terminal? You can launch instruments directly from Xcode. Open your project, press and hold on the "Run" button in the toolbar, and select "Profile". Choose your instrument of choice and voila.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Yes I am launching my own app.  I am using terminal because I am using a Ruby gem called Frank to do automated testing and using terminal is how we've chosen to go.